# How to add programatically created layout to Remoteview?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-remoteview

I am trying to add programmatically created layout to remoteview

Here is my small demo but it didn't work:

```
LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(getAppContext());
parent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

TextView tv1 = new TextView(getAppContext());
parent.addView(tv1);

parent.setId(0x7f03021b);

Remoteviews contentView = new RemoteViews(getAppContext().getPackageName(), parent.getId());
```

But the above code doesn't work.

Comment: did you get the solution?

Comment: Yes, you can assign your remoteview to bigContentView field of your  Notification.

Comment: this is not the the answer. Neo